# How to compress a file into zip format without having zip package installed

Tags: tar, zip

How to compress a file into zip format without having zip package installed? Pretty much what I need to do. I tried `tar -czf loremipsum.zip` but the format isn't a correct zip format when I try to uncompress it on windows. I'm limited and won't be able to install the package. Is there any work around?

Comment: What operating system and version are you running?

Answer (score 4):

A number of tools can create zip files, perhaps one of them will be available...

7-Zip can be used as follows:

```
7z a yourzip.zip files ...
```

Java’s JAR can also be used, as follows:

```
jar cMf yourzip.zip files ...
```

(the `M` option tells `jar` not to create a manifest).

You could also download [`zip`](http://infozip.sourceforge.net/Zip.html) and run that instead of relying on a copy installed on the system, it has hardly any dependencies:

```
wget ftp://ftp.info-zip.org/pub/infozip/unix/linux/unz551x-glibc.tgz ftp://ftp.info-zip.org/pub/infozip/unix/linux/zip23x-glibc.zip
tar xf unz551x-glibc.tgz unzip-5.51/unzip
unzip-5.51/unzip zip23x-glibc.zip zip
```

This will extract a `zip` binary which you can then use to create your zip file.

Answer (score 0):

`tar` doesn't know how to handle PKZIP files.  If you want to use `tar`, your options are "gzip" (`z`), "bzip2" (`j`), and "compress" (`Z`).

Comment: ... and `xz` (`J`), and `lzip` (`--lzip`), and `lzma` (`--lzma`), and `lzop` (`--lzop`) ;-).

Comment: Depends on your build of `tar`.

Comment: Of course. But the latest, `J`, was given its current meaning in 2009...

Comment: It does not appear on the manual page for the implementation of `tar` in MacOS 10.13, dated 12-10-2009.

Comment: Ah yes, sorry, I didn’t think BSD `tar` even supported `j`, which was rather presumptive on my part. My comment only applies to GNU `tar`.